# Reactjs - hotspot robocop type of application

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a website - and I am wondering if there is a way of using the ref aspects of an element - for a function called HotspotTarget to make the screen have an black overlay - and just like with robocop's targeting a grid lines intersect at a point of interest on the screen. A way of grabbing a user's attention for a little bit to do a call to action.
[image]

[image][image]

almost maybe loop through a batch of hotspots -- to indicate multiple calls to action - and provide like little tool tip messages or something -- does something like this exist or has been seen elsewhere - a react module already?